# Map collection of simple types to tables

Tags: c#

I have the following tables:

ResourceSet
+ Id int
[..]

ResourceTagSet
+ Id int
+ ResourceId int [FK: ResourceSet(Id)]
+ Tag

and I would like to use the following definition:

public class Resource
{
  public int Id {get; set; }

[..]

public virtual ICollection Tags { get; set; }
}

I'd need to map the collection of tags to the ResourceTagSet(Tag) values. I need only to read them (insertion is done using a SP).

Is it possible to do it with EF CodeFirst 4.1?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You must map collection of related entity. Like:

```
public class Resource
{
  public int Id {get; set; }

  [..]

  public virtual ICollection<ResourceTag> TagsSet { get; set; }
}
```

If you want just collection of strings you can add additional property:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Tags 
{
    get
    {
        return TagsSet.Select(t => t.Tag);
    }
}
```